# Joomla custom component query string to SEF URL building

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-sef-urls

I want am developing a component for joomla 3+.
I am using database to get the categories in the menu and manually creating the link like mentioned below.

```
// Creating the manual link
$linkThingsToDo = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycom&view=city&layout=thingstodo&cid[]='.$cityID.'&cat_id[]='.$value->catid);
```

Here I am using the "cid[]" for City ID and cat_id[] for Category ID and I am getting the link in address bar like this:

*joomla/index.php/city-guide-3/city/thingstodo?cid[0]=2&cat_id[0]=4*

While I want "joomla/index.php/city-guide-3/city_name_here/category_name_here"

"joomla/index.php/city-guide-3/Dubai/Chocolate"

using localhost for the testing.
What should I do to achieve the above SEF URL

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Comment: get it from joomla global configuration .. i'm not expert but i this there is an option of on/off SEF URL..